# What is the use of different types of shellcode?

Tags: shellcode

I was browsing the shellcode page in exploit-db website. What is the use of all these different shellcode programs and why should we write them?

Comment: That's a little like asking "why are there different kinds of programs?" Software exists to solve problems with certain constraints.

Comment: Shellcode is just a piece of program, basically it can do ANYTHING that the system it reside allow it to do.  e.g. as a DDoS node, provide a backdoor UI, download and run cryptominer, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**The tldr version is:**

Shellcode is just a series of commands that return a command shell. It's highly dependent on what you're attacking.

**Longer explanation:**

So shellcode is unique. It's like a fingerprint. What it is highly depends on what you're attempting to shell. Many factors come into play. OS Version, application type, application version, supported languages, certain chars you might need to not use because the application won't accept them, etc etc etc

For example, if you're attempting to exploit a website, shell code might be php that you've injected. Whereas, if you are exploiting a vulnerable windows service, your shellcode might be bytecode.

It all depends on what you're attempting to do.

[From Wikipedia - Shellcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode)

> In hacking, a shellcode is a small piece of code used as the payload
>   in the exploitation of a software vulnerability. It is called
>   "shellcode" because it typically starts a command shell from which the
>   attacker can control the compromised machine, but any piece of code
>   that performs a similar task can be called shellcode. Because the
>   function of a payload is not limited to merely spawning a shell, some
>   have suggested that the name shellcode is insufficient.[2](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Msfvenom/) However,
>   attempts at replacing the term have not gained wide acceptance.
>   Shellcode is commonly written in machine code.

**Further reading:**

I'd recommend you check out what `msfvenom` is and all its features. It might clear up a little what these payloads are and what they do.

[What is MSFVenom?](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Msfvenom/)